# select box value not set even if selected=selected attribute is set in jquery

Tags: jquery, select

I am using this in jsp. Even if my option with value "zh" is selected it displays English in select in browser and Vice versa

```
<select id="language" name="language">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">
                            请选择一种语言
                        </option>       
                        <option value="en" data-image="/businessportal/resources/core/images/blank.gif" data-imagecss="flag gb" data-title="English (United Kingdom)">English (United Kingdom)</option>
            <option value="zh" data-image="/businessportal/resources/core/images/blank.gif" data-imagecss="flag cn" data-title="中文 （中国）">中文 （中国）</option>

                    </select>
```

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking, via copy&paste into a jsfiddle this works absolutely fine. Guess: Did you neglect to _remove_ the selected attribute from the first option, and just added a second one to your `zh` option maybe …?

Comment: No First both option dont have selected attribute. I am getting value from database if its en i am selecting english if its zh i am selecting mandarin

Comment: Well then show us an actual example that reproduces the problem, please. [mcve]